# Jsoup: Getting the thread title from forum

Tags: jsoup

I doing this praser from crawled html file. This parser is suppose to extract out the thread title, user post and total view. I manage to get the to the html tag but the issue is that it unable to retrieve all of the thread title instead it only get some.

html code (Sorry for the poor align I copied from the website source code):

```
<tbody id="threadbits_forum_2">

<tr>
<td class="alt1" id="td_threadstatusicon_3396832">

    <img src="http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/img/forums/hwz/statusicon/thread_hot.gif" id="thread_statusicon_3396832" alt="" border="" />
</td>

    <td class="alt2">&nbsp;</td>


<td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_3396832" title="Updated on 3 October 2011  

Please check Price Guides for latest prices 

 A PC Buyer&#8217;s Guide that is everything to everyone is simply not possible. This     is a simple guide to putting together a PC with a local flavour. Be sure to read PC Buyer&#8217;s Guide from other media.  

If you have any...">


    <div>

            <span style="float:right">






                 <img class="inlineimg" src="http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/img/forums/hwz/misc/sticky.gif" alt="Sticky Thread" /> 
            </span>



        <font color=red><b>Sticky: </b></font>


        <a href="showthread.php?s=2a7d1dc5bbc6bf85468a79ec2e6eb86e&amp;t=3396832" id="thread_title_3396832">Buyer's Guide II: Extreme, High-End, Mid-Range, Budget, and Entry Level Systems - Part 2</a>
        <span class="smallfont" style="white-space:nowrap">(<img class="inlineimg" src="http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/img/forums/hwz/misc/multipage.gif" alt="Multi-page thread" border="0" />  <a href="showthread.php?s=2a7d1dc5bbc6bf85468a79ec2e6eb86e&amp;t=3396832">1</a> <a href="showthread.php?s=2a7d1dc5bbc6bf85468a79ec2e6eb86e&amp;t=3396832&amp;page=2">2</a> <a href="showthread.php?s=2a7d1dc5bbc6bf85468a79ec2e6eb86e&amp;t=3396832&amp;page=3">3</a> <a href="showthread.php?s=2a7d1dc5bbc6bf85468a79ec2e6eb86e&amp;t=3396832&amp;page=4">4</a> <a href="showthread.php?s=2a7d1dc5bbc6bf85468a79ec2e6eb86e&amp;t=3396832&amp;page=5">5</a> ... <a href="showthread.php?s=2a7d1dc5bbc6bf85468a79ec2e6eb86e&amp;t=3396832&amp;page=17">Last Page</a>)</span>
    </div>



    <div class="smallfont">


            <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?s=2a7d1dc5bbc6bf85468a79ec2e6eb86e&amp;u=39963', '_self')">adrianlee</span>

    </div>
```

My Coding so far:

```
 try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pageThread)))
    {
        String html = "";

        while(br.readLine() != null)
        {
            html += br.readLine() + "\n";
        }

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        //To get the thread list

        Elements threadsList = doc.select("tbody[id^=threadbits_forum]").select("tr");

        for(Element e: threadsList)
        {
            //To get the title
            System.out.println("Title: " + e.select("a[id^=thread_title]").text());
        }

        System.exit(0);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The outcome:
Title:

- Title: Want to be part of the HardwareZone Editorial Team?
- Title:
- Title: pa9797 is back to PC w a new Rig!!
- Title: [EPIC] Another first for Andyson, Platinum Modular PSU
- Title:
- Title: Which shops in SLS are good for buying a new cpu?
  .
  .
  .
  so on

Do you have workaround for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a link to the website that you want to parse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Jsoup to parse a webpage you should first get the web document in a proper way. Not that your way is wrong, but you are making it harder for yourself than it has to be.

To create a `Document` object of the webpage, start of with

```
String url = "www.google.com";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

From this document, you can make selections such as the thread title of the forum.
Another example straight from the cookbook are the `href` links.

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); //a with href
```

If you don't get the elements you want, then your selection is incorrect.

Here you select `<tr>`-elements from all the `<tbody>`-elements that has an ID that starts with `threadbits_forum`.

```
Elements threadsList = doc.select("tbody[id^=threadbits_forum]").select("tr");
```

---

Since I do not know what forum you are trying to parse, I can only look at other threadbits-forums that probably have a similar layout of their HTML.

If you look at this site, http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/corbell-ecustomer-service-center-166/, you can see that all of the topics are inside a `<td>`-class called `alt1`.

If you only select this one, you will get usernames and other stuff that use the same class, but since you only want the thread titles, you have to select the `<a>`-tag aswell.

This ends up with the following selection query

```
Elements titles = doc.select("td.alt1  a[id^=thread_title]");
```

Simulating your original question on this forum, you can do it like this:

```
    String html = "http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/corbell-ecustomer-service-center-166/";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
    Elements titles = doc.select("td.alt1  a[id^=thread_title]");
    for (Element e : titles) {
        System.out.println(e.text());
    }
```

which will result in the titles:

```
Corbell Product Warranty Policy
=MSI TwinFrozr user OC database=
Notification : Change in MSI notebook service center
RE : Forums contact window and sales & RMA reserved items @ service center :
Corbell office location. (Thanks to tayts1)
[Corbell] 'Like' Our Facebook Page and Get A chance To Win Attractive Prizes
MSI R7970 lightning problem (1 fan not spinning)
...
...
```

Hope this will help you to get the selection correctly!

Comment: Thanks alot for ur respond. I went to crawl out the forum pages and save html file on my local drive.

Comment: You should still be able to use the above method I posted.